# Passing function to child component, wrong context of 'this'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass a function to a child component. Passing the function works fine. Problem is, if I want to change property values of the parent component, this wont work since 'this' is not referencing to the parent component, but to the child component (DatagridComponent in my case)

The context of `this` seems to be the problem. See comments in code below.

Parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-management',
  templateUrl: './user-management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-management.component.css'],
})
export class UserManagementComponent implements OnInit {
  showUserDetails: boolean: false;
  showUsergroupDetails = false;

  onSelectUser() {
    this.showUsergroupDetails = false;
    this.showUserDetails = true;
    console.log(this.showUsergroupDetails); // prints false, as expected
    console.log(this.showUserDetails); // prints true, as expected
    console.log(this); // prints DatagridComponent :(
}
```

HTML, passing onSelectUser as function:

```
<app-datagrid [onSelection]="onSelectUser"></app-datagrid>
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datagrid',
  templateUrl: './datagrid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datagrid.component.css']
})
export class DatagridComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() onSelection: () => {};

  onSelectListItem(item: any) {

    // some code

    if (this.onSelection) {
      this.onSelection(); // is executed, results see comments in parent component
    }
  }
}
```

HTML of child component:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="onSelectListItem(item)">
   ....
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to look at the [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) docs, there are a bunch of different ways to implement interactions between parent-child components

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The question is more about `this` context, which you can fix it this way :

```
onSelectUser = ()=>{ // note this part 
    this.showUsergroupDetails = false;
    this.showUserDetails = true;
    console.log(this.showUsergroupDetails); // prints false, as expected
    console.log(this.showUserDetails); // prints true, as expected
    console.log(this); // prints DatagridComponent :(
}
```

We're using fat arrow to keep the context of the current component inside the function

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it addresses the question directly. In situations where the child component is part of an external lib, this is the only way to achieve this (no pun intended). Angular Material CDK (7.0.1) for example, is riddled with callbacks such as this.

Comment: I don't get why would anyone want "this" to refer to the "host" component and not the source of the function passed. Why is this behaviour?

Answer (score 13):

Use `Output` event to communicate from child component to parent component. Use `Input` property binding to pass data from `parent` to child

**Html**

```
<app-datagrid (onSelection)="onSelectUser($event)"></app-datagrid>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datagrid',
  templateUrl: './datagrid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datagrid.component.css']
})
export class DatagridComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSelection: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onSelectListItem(item: any) {
     this.onSelection.emit(item);
  }
}

//app-user-management method will receive item object
onSelectUser(item: any) {
   //here you would have item object.
}
```

See Also [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, on `this.onSelection.emit(item)` I get an error: `TS2349:Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'EventEmitter<any>' has no compatible call signatures.` Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to remove the brackets. So `this.onSelection.emit(item)` works instead of  `this.onSelection().emit(item)`. Thank you.

Comment: This is way better design than the arrow function. An event happening in a child should be an `Output` to the parent.