# Angular 4 not able to call a function of one component from one component

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a side navigation for a datatable in angular4. 
Below is the code for the same.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" position="end" style="width: 20%">

        <side-navigation [myFunction]="getAssignmentDetails()"></side-navigation>

      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
</mat-table>
</mat-sidenav-containe>
```

The `<side-navigation [myFunction]="getAssignmentDetails()"></side-navigation>` is a individual component which I have created. How can I call getAssignmentDetails() function of this individual component.

Comment: What is [myFunction]  ?

Comment: I am new to Angular 4 so I am trying different solutions from  internet. @Input() myFunction: Function; I have added this in the individual component's type script

Comment: Ok here is the answer to your question. Don't pass the function to child component. Fire an event on child, make the parent listen and call the function in parent itself. Here is how to do it using @Output and eventemitters https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690614/1504265

Comment: @vinodBhavnani I want to call a function of child component from parent component. Is it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what i understood you're tring to use an output myFunction that belongs to the SideNavigationComponent and trigger the getAssignementDetails method of the host component.

To achieve this, you have to declare the output in your SideNavigationCompoennt as follow :

```
@Component({...})
class SideNavigationComponent {
    @Output() myFunction:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

In order to use this output, you have to use the event syntaxe in the host's template :

```
<side-navigation (myFunction)="getAssignmentDetails()"></side-navigation>
```

Pay attention of the parentheses, in your sample you where using brakets (used for inputs).

In the SideNavigationComponent, to trigger the event, you'll have to use the following command :

```
this.myFunction.emit('some value');
```

---

EDIT :

In order to call a child component's method you have to reference it in your host component. The decorator @ViewChild is what you're looking for.

ex :

```
@Component({...})
class HostComponent {

    @ViewChild(SideNavigationComponent) nav:SideNavigationComponent;

    someMethod() {
        this.nav.getAssignmetDetails();
    }

}
```

Comment: I might have not used the @output event properly. My requirement is to call the getAssignmetDetails which is in the SideNavigationComponent from the host component

Comment: Ok, understood. Not sure why you would do that but it's simple. I m updating the answer.