# Angular 7 : Injected service is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, dependency-injection, jhipster

I tried to inject AccountService in the LoginService but it won't ,the accountService is undefined but in the other hand the authServiceProvider is defined .

Contrarily it injected perfectly in footerComponent.

So why the AccountService is injected perfectly in FooterComponent and it bugs in the LoginService.

I do not know where the problem came from .

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from 'app/core/auth/account.service';
import { AuthServerProvider } from 'app/core/auth/auth-jwt.service';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoginService {
    constructor(public accountService: AccountService, private authServerProvider: AuthServerProvider) {
        console.log(this.accountService); //  is undefined 
        console.log(this.authServerProvider); // is defined
}
```

This is the AuthentificationService

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthServerProvider {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private $localStorage: LocalStorageService, private $sessionStorage: SessionStorageService) {}
```

This is the AccountService

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountService {
    private userIdentity: any;
    private authenticated = false;
    private authenticationState = new Subject<any>();
    constructor(private languageService: JhiLanguageService, private sessionStorage: SessionStorageService, private http: HttpClient) {}
```

I tried to use AccountService in other component and it injected perfectly

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from 'app/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-footer',
    templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent {

    constructor( private accountService: AccountService) {
        console.log(this.accountService); // It is defined

    }
}
```

this is the app.module.ts

```
import './vendor.ts';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbDatepickerConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Ng2Webstorage } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { NgJhipsterModule } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/auth.interceptor';
import { AuthExpiredInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/auth-expired.interceptor';
import { ErrorHandlerInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/errorhandler.interceptor';
import { NotificationInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/notification.interceptor';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared';
import { CoreModule } from 'app/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { AccountModule } from './account/account.module';
import { EntityModule } from './entities/entity.module';
import * as moment from 'moment';
// jhipster-needle-angular-add-module-import JHipster will add new module here
import { JhiMainComponent, NavbarComponent, FooterComponent, PageRibbonComponent, ActiveMenuDirective, ErrorComponent } from './layouts';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-' }),
        NgJhipsterModule.forRoot({
            // set below to true to make alerts look like toast
            alertAsToast: false,
            alertTimeout: 5000,
            i18nEnabled: true,
            defaultI18nLang: 'en'
        }),
        SharedModule.forRoot(),
        CoreModule,
        HomeModule,
        AccountModule,
        // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
        EntityModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [JhiMainComponent, NavbarComponent, ErrorComponent, PageRibbonComponent, ActiveMenuDirective, FooterComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [JhiMainComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private dpConfig: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
        this.dpConfig.minDate = { year: moment().year() - 100, month: 1, day: 1 };
    }
}
```

and this is the core.module .

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import locale from '@angular/common/locales/en';
@NgModule({
    imports: [HttpClientModule],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        Title,
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useValue: 'en'
        },
        DatePipe
    ]
})
export class CoreModule {
    constructor() {
        registerLocaleData(locale);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you please share your module definitions?

Comment: Can you make sure both of your services are in the providers array in your app.module.ts file

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu I add the module definition

Comment: @O.MeeKoh no they aren't because of  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but you may be missing something in order to inject a service into another service when using the providedIn:root property. Try simply simply removing the @Injectable() from your AccountService service, and but specify it into the app.module.ts providers array. See if this works

Comment: @O.MeeKoh thanks for your help. It works when I add it in the app.module but I dont know why it does not with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) even both of theme do the same job .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing function to child component, wrong context of 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690530/passing-function-to-child-component-wrong-context-of-this)

Comment: Resolved this issue just by adding HttpClientModule in imports section in AppModule.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> You should always provide your service in the root injector unless
>   there is a case where you want the service to be available only if the
>   consumer imports a particular @NgModule.

try to add your service you want to inject in `providers : [ ]` in your `core.module`

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import locale from '@angular/common/locales/en';
@NgModule({
    imports: [HttpClientModule],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        AccountService,
        Title,
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useValue: 'en'
        },
        DatePipe
    ]
})
export class CoreModule {
    constructor() {
        registerLocaleData(locale);
    }
}
```

and in your AccountService replace  `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` with `@Injectable()`

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
    private userIdentity: any;
    private authenticated = false;
    private authenticationState = new Subject<any>();
    constructor(private languageService: JhiLanguageService, private sessionStorage: SessionStorageService, private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Comment: Thanks bro It works but I do not know why it works in this case , I think in angular 7 if we used provideIn property there is no need to add the service into providers .

Comment: Would love an elaboration on why and how this works. A link to docs would be nice as well.

Comment: @span here is a [link](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providers) trying to explain you how does provider works

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd been all over it without resolving my issue. Until I remembered the old days of using var this = that etc... I was getting undefined since I was passing a normal function as a callback instead of an arrow function. They have different this scope. Hopefully someone stumbles over this :)

Comment: I think the point of the question is why doesn't it work with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`. This answer mitigates the problem behind this question but basically goes against the Angular docs, that say that `Beginning with Angular 6.0, the preferred way to create a singleton service is to set providedIn to root on the service's @Injectable() decorator.`

Comment: @RidaeHAMDANI, did you come to know, why it's not working with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })?

Comment: @rahul-upadhyay Unfortunately I did not

Answer (score 33):

The same thing happened to me, the solution was the one [mentioned by the user **span**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230263/angular-7-injected-service-is-undefined#comment100857633_55231138)

> -> Passing arrow function instead of regular function in the callback. Arrow functions don't have its own ***this***.

Difference between regular functions and arrow functions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions/)

Comment: This is [covered in more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690530/angular-passing-function-to-child-component-wrong-context-of-this)

Comment: I can't see the relation between the code in the question, and arrow functions. The OP only talks about `constructor`s, he nevers calls `new LoginService(...)` so why the hell would there be a context issue ?

Answer (score 0):

HttpClientModule is required for HttpClient. Just import in AppModule.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule //add this as fix, simple
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when by a mistake I used an interface instead of a class implementation in the injection inside of the problematic service.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing the issue to this day using functional guards,
double check if you are importing

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
```

and not

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

This solved my issue, perhaps this fixes your issue.