# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when calling method from service

Tags: angular

**Hi guys, I'm trying to fetch data from API using this service and console log the data. I'm getting this error code of the component and the service provided below ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTweets')**

```
   the service:

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FetchDataService {
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      getTweets(){
        return this.http.get(environment.API_END_POINT + 'tweets');
      }
    }
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
   

     the component:
        
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {LiveAnnouncer} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { DashboardService } from '../dashboard.service';
import {MatSort, Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatButton } from '@angular/material';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ShareDataService } from '../share-data.service';
import { FetchDataService } from '../fetch-data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private fetchData: FetchDataService, private 
 dashboardService: DashboardService ,private shareData: ShareDataService,private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer,private router:Router) { }
  @ViewChild(MatSort,{static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchTweets();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  fetchTweets(){
      this.fetchData.getTweets()
        .subscribe((success) => {
          console.log(success)
          },
          (err)=>{
            console.log(err);
          });
  }

  applyFilter(event){
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase()
  }

  onGetReport(name){
    this.fetchTweets();
    console.log(name);
    this.shareData.set(name);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/reports');
  }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  /** Announce the change in sort state for assistive technology. */
  announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {
    // This example uses English messages. If your application supports
    // multiple language, you would internationalize these strings.
    // Furthermore, you can customize the message to add additional
    // details about the values being sorted.
    if (sortState.direction) {
      this._liveAnnouncer.announce(`Sorted ${sortState.direction}ending`);
    } else {
      this._liveAnnouncer.announce('Sorting cleared');
    }
  }
}
```

Hi guys, I'm trying to fetch data from API using this service and console log the data. I'm getting this error code of the component and the service provided bellow ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTweets')

```
DashboardComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTweets')
    at DashboardComponent.fetchTweets (dashboard.component.ts:73:22)
    at DashboardComponent.ngOnInit (dashboard.component.ts:64:10)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24503:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102:1)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36124:36)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36067:1)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DashboardComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:11:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36055:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35067:1)
View_DashboardComponent_Host_0 @ DashboardComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:6
```

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTweets')`

This error is raised when calling : `this.fetchData.getTweets()`, please provide the code where fetchData object is initiated

Comment: edited the code and provided the whole component

Comment: Great, could you try turning fetchTweets() as an arrow function as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57588867/19330634) suggests ?

Comment: something else is going on here that isn't in the question. the code as written here is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this and see that you get...

```
this.http.get(environment.API_END_POINT + 'tweets').pipe(
.map(res: any)=>{
   console.log(res);
}
).subscribe();
```

Also did you PROVIDE your tweets service in the app module?

Comment: he should use the tap operator instead for debugging

Comment: Hi Judson, it's the same thing.. the error is raised when calling the method and not when fetching and retrieving the data

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I provided the service to the parent component providers[] and imported the HttpClientModule to the appmodule imports.

Comment: just an FYI, since this service was marked as providedIn root, then you shouldn't have needed to do this (besides importing the httpclientmodule, but that should've thrown different errors earlier). this all indicates you're doing something non standard that is breaking normal angular functions which means more will go wrong